# Prometheus missing metrics on Chainlink Node

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana, chainlink, prometheus-node-exporter

Using a docker network with chainlink v1.0.1 i've set up a node-exporter/prometheus/grafana monitoring stack. Upon looking at various dashboards used by others (specifically Link River & Vulcan.Link), it looks as though I am missing metrics in prometheus.

Here's a list of metrics I have related to the CL node:

- eth_balance
- flux_monitor_response_size_bytes_bucket
- flux_monitor_response_size_bytes_count
- flux_monitor_response_size_bytes_sum
- gas_updater_all_gas_percetiles
- gas_updater_set_gas_price
- head_tracker_current_head
- head_tracker_eth_connection_errors
- head_tracker_heads_received
- head_tracker_very_old_head
- max_unconfirmed_blocks
- max_unconfirmed_tx_age
- pipeline_runs_queued
- pipeline_task_runs_queued
- tx_manager_gas_bump_exceeds_limit
- tx_manager_num_gas_bumps
- tx_manager_num_tx_reverted
- unconfirmed_transactions
- up
- uptime_seconds

Here's a list of what looks to be missing:

- - pipeline_run_errors
  - pipeline_run_total_time_to_completion
  - pipeline_task_execution_time
  - job_subscriber_subscriptions
  - head_tracker_heads_in_queue
  - head_tracker_callback_execution_duration
  - run_queue_queue_size
  - run_status_update_total
  - adapter_perform_complete_total
  - txpool_local
  - txpool_queued
  - txpool_pending

I've tried a few different version implementations and that doesn't seem to be the issue. Excerpt from my Prometheus.yml file:

- job_name: 'chainlink_p1'
  static_configs:

  - targets: ['CONTAINER-ID:6688']  # add the container ID of your running Node and if you use a different port you can also configure it
    metrics_path: '/metrics'
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true

Any thoughts on why these metrics could be missing and how to remedy? Feels like an issue with the exporter, but its a bit beyond me at this point.